# can not get values less than 1

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

When I run my code I get all the names, average prices and average sales per day. However some items on the website I am scraping have less than 1 sale per day. How can I find these items? The website uses an api with all the data needed. The sales per day appears to be the 'count'.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import mean
import re
import numpy
import statistics
import xlsxwriter
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import pandas as pd

exclusions=[]
dfs=[]
dupcheck=[] 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('waxpeerdb.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
workbook.close()


item=[]
listo=[]
at_end=False
URL = (
    "https://waxpeer.com/api/data/index/?skip={offset}&sort=best_deals&game=csgo&all=0"
)

offset = 0

while at_end ==False:

    response = requests.get(URL.format(offset=offset)).json()
    for data in response["items"]:

        namer=(data["name"])

        listo.append(namer)

        namelist=sorted(list(listo))
```

The items from the site are appended to a namelist and then used to get the data I desire.
for names in namelist:

```
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}

            data = {"name":names}

            r = requests.post('https://waxpeer.com/api/get-sales-history', headers=headers, 
json=data)

            history=r.json()

            count=[i['count'] for i in history['data']]

            AveragePrice=numpy.mean([i['avg'] for i in history['data']])

            counter = [list(map(int, x)) for x in count]
            print(counter)

            avgn=(numpy.mean(counter))

            itemois=pd.DataFrame({ 'Names':[namer],'Average Sales Per Day': [avgn], 'AveragePrice': 
[AveragePrice]})

            dfs.append(itemois)

            offset += 50

            if offset > 10000:

                at_end=True

            else:
                print(offset)
```

The database is then printed and added to an excel file.

```
itemois = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)         


print(itemois)
itemois.to_excel('waxpeerdb.xlsx')
```

Comment: If I understand you right, the items with less than 1 sale per day don't show in the API?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the items that don't show in the api or if the code is somehow excluding or miscalculating them.